# Can you copy a list in an element of another list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I would like to know if there is a possibility of copying an entire list on an element of another one.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = []
b[0] = list(a)
print(b)
```

It gives the error: `list assignment index out of range`

But if we do not copy it and we only put it there:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [a]
print(b)
```

It works and prints: `[[1, 2, 3]]`

Can this be done?

Comment: you can also do `b=[list(a)]`.  See answers below for the reason you have index assignment errors.

Comment: Neither answer speaks to copying the list rather than referencing it. `b = [a]; a[0] = 9` will modify `b[0]`. You can use a boundless slice to quickly copy a list (`b = [a[:]]`)

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks for the help. I got it to work finally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It gives the error: "list assignment index out of range"

Because you have created `b` *as an empty list* with `b=[]` and then you try and ***access*** the first element `[0]` of list `b` with `b[0]` when executing `b[0] = list(a)`, and that index **doesn't exist** for an empty list.

To add a value to a list, you generally always use the [**`list.append()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = []

b.append(a)  # similar to b = [a] but more intuitive.
print(b)     # prints b = [[1, 2, 3]]
```

Simple, clear and concise.

---

#### A Note of caution:

`b.append(a)` and `b.append(list(a))` are two ***similarly looking different*** things.

`b.append(a)` (similar to `b = [a]`) copies a **reference** of `a` in `b` while `b.append(list(a))` ***creates a new list*** from the values of `a` and adds it to the list `b`. Because lists are mutable, this has comfusing implications when manipulating the internal list.

This becomes clearer with an example, where `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b=[]` in each example:

With `b.append(a)`:

```
b.append(a)
print(b)     # prints b = [[1, 2, 3]]

# Now if we modify a:
a.append(4)  # a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Changes are visible in b:
print(b)     # b = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

With `b.append(list(a))`:

```
b.append(list(a))
print(b)     # prints b = [[1, 2, 3]]

# Now if we modify a:
a.append(4)  # a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Changes are NOT visible in b:
print(b)     # b = [[1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Now I understand why the error was there. I can not use the append function as I do not want the a to be referenced but I got it to work in other way using the firs discovery :D. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Python lists do not allow you to modify elements with an index **equal to** or greater than the length of the list. The first element of an empty list does not exist. You need to add it with `b.append(list(a))`

Comment: It **copies** the list instead of **adding a refrence to it**.

Comment: I got it to work in some other way, but thank you for your help anyway.